# My Application closed by this Error : Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed an application (using vs 2010 C#).
After some time (1 hour or 3 or any ) my application is closed by this exception:
**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt**.
I don't know which part of my code causes this exception. What do I have to do?

Note that I am using System.Data.SQLite dll and a dll (ocx file) from another software in my application and 5 Versions of this application is running simultaneously.

> ```
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageA(MSG& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
> at IranAir.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Gabriel\Program.cs:line 18
> at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
> at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
> ```

I have a com object in my application.it happens at the end of the one of its events.
this com object has an event named Recieved_Message and after this event execute completely I got this error.

```
 void a_Received(object sender, ReceivedEvent e)
{
    //when processing finished successfully and it reachs to the close        bracket , this exception fired.
}
```

so what is the problem?

Comment: can you catch the exception?

Comment: no,it just close the application.

Comment: is any way to understand which part of my code causes this exception (any software or any other ways to trace it) .it closed after a while when just application is open just.(and sometimes during execution.)

Comment: An AccessViolationException is generally caused by unmanaged code.   You have a very obvious candidate here, use a telephone to get support from the owner or author of this COM component.  If nobody picks up then stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you built your application as x86 and the amount of memory your application is using is steadily increasing? If that is the case, you are probably hitting the 2GB memory usage for 32-bit applications.

Comment: no . maximum use is about 30 KB.i have 4GB ram in my server.you mean my application has some sort of limitation of using ram?so how to increase it?

Comment: If you application only uses about 30KB of RAM, it is very unlikely that this is the issue you are facing. From your log, it is difficult to tell what it might be. The best I can do is offer a guess based on the log. I'd suggest you make a call to the component's author like @Hans Passant suggested